# Parametric polymorphism in scala

Tags: scala, types, parameters, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I'm trying to implement parametric polymorphism to devolve functions that have case matching statements that use `asInstanceOf[]`. I need to match the type of arguments to a classes in another package of the project which accepts parameters. I've tried this code:

```
def abc[A](x: A, i: Int): Any =
{
    x(i)
}
```

On running, I get an error saying `A does not take parameters`. How can I match `A` to few of the classes in `project1.package1` folder? These classes are similar to an Array/Vector and `x(i)` returns `i`th element. Each class takes a different datatype (like Int, Double, String etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the classes accept parameters, they *may* be subtypes of `Function1`. Unfortunately not all

So you could write:

```
def abc[A <: Function1[Int, _]](x: A, i: Int): Any = {
    x(i)
}
```

But that doesn't work for *all* objects that take parameters, for example case class companion objects. So to get around that you could use a structural type. Something like:

```
 def abc[A <: {def apply(i: Int): Any } ](x: A, i: Int): Any = {
    x(i)
}
```

Basically what we are doing here is accepting a subtype of any type that has an `apply` method with an `Int` i.e. it takes an `Int` parameter.

It should be noted that the structural type will give you grief if you try to generalise the input type from `Int` to an arbitrary `T`

Comment: And structural types also use reflection, so will perform worse than direct calls. In many circumstances this is still acceptable, since but it's important to keep in mind.